# Shadowing a member function with a function argument

Tags: c++

Take the following class for an example

```
class A
{
    int m_c;
public:
    void B(int C);    
    void C();
};
```

This would give out the following warning if i compiled with the `-Wshadow` argument

```
memberFuncArg.cpp: In member function ‘void A::B(int)’:
memberFuncArg.cpp:12:16: warning: declaration of ‘C’ shadows a member of 'this' [-Wshadow]
 void A::B(int C)
                ^
```

What are the consequences of shadowing a member function with an argument to another member function like this?

Comment: You mean besides having to use `this->C()` to call the member function?

Comment: This should never happen in a well-written code snippet as variable/parameter names are supposed to be *nouns/pronouns*, while method names are supposed to be *verbs*

Comment: But for flags, Ive seen the variable/parameter and the function are given the same name on some occassions. For example to check if the flag is set, a function `isSet()` and to set the particular flag `setStatus(bool isSet)`. Maybe its not the best practice.

Comment: I'd write it as `void SetStatus(bool status)` or `void SetStatus(bool bStatus)` depending upon the coding guidelines to be followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the consequences of shadowing a member function with an argument

The consequence is that a programmer who reads the code may be confused about which entity is being referred to by `C`. They may have become accustomed to the fact that `C` is a member function, and reasonably (but mistakenly) expect this to be the case within `B` as well.

The consequence is much worse when the argument is not of type `int`, but of some other type that can be invoked with same arguments as the member function. The confused programmer would then read or write `C()` and expect it to call the member function, but the behaviour would be different than expected.